# Count of Array (within an Array) to determin UIView width

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, uiview

I am trying to figure out how to get the count of an array within an array (do not know the technical term).

I am creating groups of UIViews, and I would like the width of these groups to change dynamically depending on the number of UIViews that are within the group.

The only way I know how to do this (potentially) is to find the count of by `blockTitles` (group), but I am having issues pulling this count from within my `palletViewConstraint()` function.

Looking for help with this solution or recommendations for better solutions.

Cheers!

```
func mainViews(inputView: UIView){

    <...>

    //POPULATING PALLET WITH BLOCKS
    let blockTitles1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    let blockTitles2 = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
    let blockTitles3 = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]
    let blockTitles4 = ["16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
    let blockTitles5 = ["21", "22", "23", "24", "25"]

    var group1 = createBlockGroup(blockTitles1)
    var group2 = createBlockGroup(blockTitles2)
    var group3 = createBlockGroup(blockTitles3)
    var group4 = createBlockGroup(blockTitles4)
    var group5 = createBlockGroup(blockTitles5)

    palletView.addSubview(group1)
    palletView.addSubview(group2)
    palletView.addSubview(group3)
    palletView.addSubview(group4)
    palletView.addSubview(group5)

    palletViewConstraint(palletView, groups: [group1, group2, group3, group4, group5], blockTitles: [blockTitles1, blockTitles2, blockTitles3, blockTitles4, blockTitles5])

}

func createBlock(title: String) -> UIView{

    let block = UIView()
    block.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    block.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let blockLabel = UILabel()
    blockLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    blockLabel.text = title
    blockLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    blockLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    block.addSubview(blockLabel)

    return block
}

func createBlockGroup(blockTitles: [String]) -> UIView {

    var blocks = [UIView]()
    let blockGroups = UIView()
    blockGroups.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    blockGroups.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    for blockTitle in blockTitles{
        let block = createBlock(blockTitle)
        blocks.append(block)
        blockGroups.addSubview(block)
    }

    blockConstraint(blocks, mainView: blockGroups)

    return blockGroups

}

func blockConstraint(blocks: [UIView], mainView: UIView){

    <...>

}

func palletViewConstraint(inputView: UIView, groups: [UIView], blockTitles: [[String]]){

    print(blockTitles.count)

}

func mainViewConstraints(inputView: UIView, pallet: UIScrollView, canvas: UIView){

    <...>
}



}
```

Comment: I'd like to help you, but can you post a picture of what you are trying to achieve (as it is kind of vague with just this code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the count of an array within an array by using

```
mainArr[0].count
```

This will get the count of the first array in the mainArr.

I would recommend subclassing `UIView` and using a convenience initializer to set the frame to a value divided by the number of views (which can be accessed by a delegate pattern).

Here is an example of `UIView` subclass that I have set up to dynamically adjust a grid of subviews. The whole project can be found on my github page: https://github.com/cmako10/UI-View-Groups

Here is the subclass:

```
class GroupView: UIView {

  var rows: Int!
  var columns: Int!
  var size: CGSize!
  var origin: CGPoint!

  enum TypeToAdd: String {
    case row = "Row"
    case column = "Column"
  }

  enum AlterAction: String {
    case add = "Add"
    case delete = "Delete"
  }

  convenience init(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize, columns: Int, rows: Int) {
    self.init(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
    self.size = size
    self.origin = origin
    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns
  }

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    frame.size.width = size.width
    frame.size.height = size.height
    super.drawRect(rect)
    for view in self.subviews {
      view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    let width = size.width / CGFloat(columns)
    let height = size.height / CGFloat(rows)
    let subviewSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    for y in 0..<rows {
      for x in 0..<columns {
        let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(x) * width), y: (CGFloat(y) * height)), size: subviewSize))

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: subviewSize))
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15, weight: 10.0)
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.center = CGPoint(x: newView.frame.midX, y: newView.frame.midY)
        label.text = "[\(x), \(y)]"
        newView.addSubview(label)

        if y % 2 == 0 {
          if x % 2 == 0 {
            newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
          } else {
            newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
          }
        } else {
          if x % 2 == 0 {
            newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
          } else {
            newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
          }
        }
        addSubview(newView)
      }
    }
  }

  func alter(type: TypeToAdd, action: AlterAction){
    switch type {
    case .column:
      switch action {
      case .add:
        columns = columns + 1
      case .delete:
        columns = columns - 1
      }
    case .row:
      switch action {
      case .add:
        rows = rows + 1
      case .delete:
        rows = rows - 1
      }
    }
    setNeedsDisplay()
  }
}
```

You should download and examine the Xcode project. The general idea to dynamically update the `UIView` is to remove all subviews and then re-add the subviews in `drawRect` and then call `setNeedDisplay` whenever you need to update the contents of the `GroupView`.

**Edit:**

To access the counts of the subarrays of `blockTitles` I see two possible solutions.

1. Use a for loop, define a constant at the beginning of the loop to be equal to the count of the subarray at "i", then put the code inside `palletViewConstraint` after that and reference the `count` constant as needed.
2. Define a variable to hold the count values (an array of `Int`s) at the start of `palletViewConstraint` use the high-level function `map` to append all the blockTitle counts to the previously defined variable, use a for loop and the defined count array to run the rest of your `palletViewConstraint`.

**Examples:**

Example 1:

```
func palletViewConstraint(inputView: UIView, groups: [UIView], blockTitles: [[String]]){
   //Do this so the count is not recalculated each for loop
   let blockTitlesCount = blockTitles.count
   for i in blockTitlesCount {
      let subArrCount = blockTitles[i].count
      //The rest of your palletViewConstraint Code that references subArrCount

   }
 }
```

Example 2:

```
func palletViewConstraint(inputView: UIView, groups: [UIView], blockTitles: [[String]]){
   var countArr = [Int]()

   arr.map { (subArr) in
      countArr.append(subArr.count)
   }

   for count in countArr {
      //Your code referencing the count of each subArr

   }
}
```

If you need elaboration please ask!

Comment: @Geppelt See my edits for an example of what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But the issue is that I would have to restructure a lot to implement your feedback. I am simply trying to find a solution to get the string count in my blockTitles to the constraints I setup for the groups. As of now the arrays looks something like this:

`group[blockTitle1["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], blockTitle2["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]...]` I can get the group.count, but what I really am wanting is group[index].count. This count would then be multiple to define the width of each group as they are added as subviews. Make sense?

Comment: Where do you want to be able to access group[index].count? I'm unsure why you can't. Can you post the code for that area, so I can try to help? @Geppelt

Comment: I am trying to call it with the `blockTitles` in my `palletViewConstraint` function.

Comment: @Geppelt see my edits for ways to access the counts of the subarrays of the `blockTitles` parameter